# Include Ionic Dark Theme

Tags: ionic2

I know Ionic 2 ships with a dark theme (the `ionic-angular` node module ships with the file `css/ionic.dark.css`).

How do I import it in my Ionic application's SASS?

I've tried to `@import ionic-angular/css/ionic.dark.css` in both `src/app/app.scss` and `src/theme/components.scss` but the output is visually the same as the starter theme.

---

**Edit** to add my `ionic info`:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
Node Version: v6.9.1
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Update in ionic 2.0:**

Replacing '@import "ionic.theme.default"' to '@import "ionic.theme.dark"' activates the dark theme.

**ionic RC version**

Ionic's default theme gets selected from from variables.scss file.

Replace '`@import "ionic.theme.default"`' to '`@import "ionic.theme.dark"`' to activate the dark theme.

Also remove the below lines of code from variables.scss

```
$text-color:        #000;
$background-color:  #fff;
```

These variables overrides the default variable in dark theme. You can either remove to get standard dark theme or play around with this to get your own color for background and text color in dark theme.

Comment: Excellent. where i can get a list of color themes available?